# Qt ComboBox не растягивается по ширине самого длинного элемента на Linux

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, astra-linux

В коде прописано:

```
setSizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox::AdjustToContents);
```

На Windows 7 работает прекрасно, но на Astra Linux 1.5-1.6 нет. Версия Qt 4.8. В закрытом состоянии combobox маленький,когда раскрываю - также не растягивается по ширине элемента, сами элементы все равно прописаны не полностью, а с троеточием (типа "Абв...юя"). Если выбрать что-то, тогда адаптируется под него и растягивается, но при раскрытии списка элементы все равно с троеточием. Может быть есть еще какие-нибудь способы сделать combobox по ширине самого длинного элемента?
Пробовала так:

```
 int width = minimumSizeHint().width(); 
 setMinimumWidth(width);
```

Окно ComboBox не вписывается в интерфейс, галка для открытия списка за пределами границ таблицы, в которой находится. Но при открытии элементы списка все равно с троеточиями, не полностью.

Comment: Попробовать лейауты?

Comment: layout для расположения в нем combobox, верно? Я работаю с классом, который наследуется от combobox, и за его пределы мне лучше не лазить. layout используется выше, и нужно, чтобы он менялся при изменении размера combobox, не зная ничего о его элементах.Внутри класса  я могу использовать layout?

Comment: Вообще, отсюда не видать, но QComboBox наследуется от QWidget, поэтому можете. Наверное )

Comment: вопросу бы помогло, если бы в него добавили скрин и [mcve]...